# Return several lists from “foreach” in parallel when list elements are updated from already existing lists

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using a “foreach” loop in R with two lists. I would like that the loop returns the two lists similar to a simple “for” loop but I can’t get the desired output.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(doSNOW)

list_1 <- list(partition = as.list(rep(NA, 10)))

for(h in 1:1){
  
    list_2 <- as.list(rep(NA, 10))
    
    cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
    registerDoSNOW(cl)
    
    iteration_progress <- function(n){cat(sprintf("Task %d out of %d completed\n", n, 10))}
    
    test <- foreach::foreach(i = 1:10, .packages = c("dplyr"), .options.snow = list(progress = iteration_progress), .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
      ## for(i in 1:10){
      
      list_1[[h]][[i]] <- data.frame(a = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100), b = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100))
  
      list_2[[i]] <- data.frame(a = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100), b = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100))
      
      return(list(list_1, list_2))

    }
    
    parallel::stopCluster(cl)
}
```

Here is the result:

```
> head(test)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]]$partition
[[1]][[1]]$partition[[1]]
          a        b
1  9.539889 23.04976
2  5.822633 53.84812
3 50.235693 15.25160
4 38.280393 79.44812
5 95.080098 59.21978

[[1]][[1]]$partition[[2]]
[1] NA

[[1]][[1]]$partition[[3]]
[1] NA
....

[[10]][[2]]
[[10]][[2]][[1]]
         a         b
1 50.71016 12.262205
2 57.20248 24.023991
3 37.77095 78.613931
4 79.51537  3.549685
5 24.41080 46.590377

[[10]][[2]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[10]][[2]][[3]]
[1] NA

    ...
```

Here is the desired result (I think that it's something like this):

```
[[1]]
$partition
$partition[[1]]
          a        b
1 39.859322 73.83619
2  2.020849 65.61457
3 64.517250 17.11099
4 55.077582 65.69402
5 32.028484 56.92836

$partition[[2]]
         a        b
1 80.41741  6.22215
2 85.02102 82.77870
3 70.11590 21.97767
4 34.12713 84.11255
5 34.61829 43.28926
...

[[2]]
[[1]]
          a         b
1 45.090343 30.427827
2 73.550851 25.247398
3 16.185700 29.389445
4 70.439002 50.097795
5  4.760741  8.536996

[[2]]
         a        b
1 89.63213 14.69734
2 39.76736 54.60903
3 94.89296 78.55906
4 99.64688 68.16239
5 60.26470 74.30619
...
```

In particular, the two lists should be like the ones obtained with a simple "for(i in 1:10)" loop and if possible, I would like to retrieve the two lists from the desired result as follows:

```
output_list_1 <- test[[1]]
output_list_2 <- test[[2]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested how the ["foreach" loop](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html) operates in parallel mode. Unlike a regular "for" loop, variables are not shared across different workers (iterations) in a "foreach" loop. Each worker gets a copy of the current R session (without the changes made by other workers), which means that when the workers modify `list_1` and `list_2`, they are each modifying their own copy, and these modifications are not reflected in the main session or in other workers.

A better approach would be to have each worker (iteration) return the result directly, rather than trying to modify a list in-place.

```r
test <- foreach::foreach(i = 1:10, .options.snow = list(progress = iteration_progress), .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
  df1 <- data.frame(a = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100), b = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100))
  df2 <- data.frame(a = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100), b = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100))

  list(list_1 = df1, list_2 = df2)
}
```

Each worker (iteration) is returning a result directly, as a list that includes `list_1` and `list_2`. Each of these lists contains the generated data frames `df1` and `df2`. The `foreach` function will then combine these returned results into a list, `test`, where each element is the result from one iteration. This approach, returning the result from each worker, is much safer and more reliable when dealing with parallel processing, as opposed to trying to modify a shared resource.

So, the line `list(list_1 = df1, list_2 = df2)` is creating a list with two named elements (which are data frames in this case), and that list is returned as the result for each worker. The outer `foreach` call then collects these results into a larger list, where each element is one worker's returned list.

After the generation, you should restructure your `test` list to have the expected structure for `output_list_1` and `output_list_2`.

```
output_list_1 <- lapply(test, function(x) x$list_1)
output_list_2 <- lapply(test, function(x) x$list_2)
```

My current test:

```r
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(doSNOW)

list_1 <- list(partition = as.list(rep(NA, 10)))

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

iteration_progress <- function(n){cat(sprintf("Task %d out of %d completed\n", n, 10))}

test <- foreach::foreach(i = 1:10, .options.snow = list(progress = iteration_progress), .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
  df1 <- data.frame(a = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100), b = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100))
  df2 <- data.frame(a = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100), b = runif(5, min = 1, max = 100))

  list(list_1 = df1, list_2 = df2)
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)

# Extract the results
output_list_1 <- lapply(test, function(x) x$list_1)
output_list_2 <- lapply(test, function(x) x$list_2)

# Check the results
stopifnot(length(output_list_1) == 10)
stopifnot(length(output_list_2) == 10)

# Print the results
str(output_list_1)
str(output_list_2)
```

[image: RStudio]

I get:

```
> head(test)
[[1]]
[[1]]$list_1
         a         b
1 38.09010  6.927731
2 59.88176 76.971436
3 41.39410 68.101423
4 99.92180 29.982713
5 67.77013 98.395956

[[1]]$list_2
          a         b
1 99.454696 11.352044
2  4.333406 44.888147
3 14.369086 87.742845
4 34.233738  4.711044
5 24.759839 83.304572


[[2]]
[[2]]$list_1
         a         b
1 97.29568 94.576222
2 18.05499 90.251814
3 76.22384  6.154534
4 44.48107 67.642049
5 34.57727 61.709584

[[2]]$list_2
          a        b
1 48.761841 62.72727
2 70.806091 49.68349
3  4.878827 89.58200
4 69.244979 77.82727
5 70.951033  5.94136


[[3]]
[[3]]$list_1
          a        b
1 51.543344 30.63884
2 93.803972 99.55169
3 39.121449 15.77124
4 62.200827 79.93441
5  3.938176 35.78175

[[3]]$list_2
          a        b
1  4.552992 96.96822
2  4.111931 91.53826
3 44.129487 70.17699
4 43.339853 94.96077
5 73.987056 42.89454


[[4]]
[[4]]$list_1
         a        b
1 65.74309 24.97559
2 29.25263 61.58556
3 33.67295 93.78801
4 54.60820 10.08641
5 57.41684 60.95383

[[4]]$list_2
          a        b
1 70.757634 90.64979
2 75.927533 63.42867
3 78.893102 47.59998
4 81.495705 96.39439
5  7.553589 52.89380


[[5]]
[[5]]$list_1
         a        b
1 76.32759 80.91096
2 36.01775 10.89035
3 77.66053 64.25386
4 88.07327 63.10123
5 22.62640 44.73653

[[5]]$list_2
         a         b
1 42.26971 21.261144
2 93.45123 84.421311
3 88.66621  1.182257
4 82.67811  8.397177
5 77.42432 19.019766


[[6]]
[[6]]$list_1
          a         b
1 94.623681 52.154517
2  5.201013 26.863191
3 42.137354  6.845838
4 26.115025 97.393823
5 83.196664 24.728960

[[6]]$list_2
         a         b
1 58.44716 55.407392
2 67.67350 98.693118
3 32.15317  9.905212
4 13.50472  8.595477
5 70.20648 65.902455
```